# Rearrange/order array based on it's object values added together

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an array of multiple objects which have 4 key-value (could have more) pairs and an identifier. Is there a way to change order of the array - ascending/descending, based on what `Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4` add up?

```js
const array = [
{
 'Val1': 10,
 'Val2': 20,
 'Val3': 30,
 'Val4': 40 , // Val1 + Val2 + Val3 + Val4 = 100 
 'identifier': 'Column1'
},
{
 'Val1': 20,
 'Val2': 30,
 'Val3': 40,
 'Val4': 50, // Val1 + Val2 + Val3 + Val4 = 140 
 'identifier': 'Column2' 
}
]
```

In this example, let's say I want to change the array to descending order and expected result would be -

```js
const array = [
{
 'Val1': 20,
 'Val2': 30,
 'Val3': 40,
 'Val4': 50, // Val1 + Val2 + Val3 + Val4 = 140 
 'identifier': 'Column2' 
}
{
 'Val1': 10,
 'Val2': 20,
 'Val3': 30,
 'Val4': 40, // Val1 + Val2 + Val3 + Val4 = 100 
 'identifier': 'Column1'
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const array = [
{
 'Val1': 10,
 'Val2': 20,
 'Val3': 30,
 'Val4': 40 , // Val1 + Val2 + Val3 + Val4 = 100 
 'identifier': 'Column1'
},
{
 'Val1': 20,
 'Val2': 30,
 'Val3': 40,
 'Val4': 70, // Val1 + Val2 + Val3 + Val4 = 160 
 'identifier': 'Column3' 
},
{
 'Val1': 20,
 'Val2': 30,
 'Val3': 40,
 'Val4': 50, // Val1 + Val2 + Val3 + Val4 = 140 
 'identifier': 'Column2' 
}], sum=a=>a.Val1+a.Val2+a.Val3+a.Val4;

console.log("ascending",array.sort((a,b)=>sum(a)-sum(b)));
console.log("descending",array.sort((a,b)=>sum(a)-sum(b)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.sort` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

In your case you just need to add them up and subtract.  If you do `a-b`, this will give you an ascending ordering.  So for descending, you just need `b-a`.

eg.

```js
const array = [{"Val1":10,"Val2":20,"Val3":30,"Val4":40,"identifier":"Column1"},{"Val1":20,"Val2":30,"Val3":40,"Val4":50,"identifier":"Column2"}];

array.sort((a,b) => 
  + b.Val1 + b.Val2 + b.Val3 + b.Val4
  - a.Val1 - a.Val2 - a.Val3 - a.Val4
);
  
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just sort `object`, as different engines will show your object differently.
For example, sorted `object` in V8 and SpiderMonkey someday will compile differently.

So, the robust solution is to turn your data into an array.
You should never make assumptions about the order of elements in a `JavaScript object`.